# Add Objects to custom listView with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add an whole object to my listview using Firebase.
Have been illustration this with a image because sometimes an image is just easier than text.

[image: Firebase database tree]

Firebase tutorials show how to return each child as an item and display it with Firebase UI and I want to almost do the same thing but the difference is that I want the whole object to be the child and the childs inside that object will be additional information for each listitem.

So in my image I have object **Camping** and the "Mountains",  "Nature", "Place".
In an custom listView I want the different values be set to textViews.to be the

This is how I get the child items with the Firebase UI:

```
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Firebase items = rootRef.child("events");
    final FirebaseListAdapter<String> fireAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,String.class,R.layout.list_item,items) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {
            TextView testText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            testText.setText(s);
            trucks.add(s);
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(fireAdapter);
}
```

**UPDATE**

> > Here is code how I get **mountains** value to be set to a textview in my custom listview layout:

```
private void getUpdatesEvents(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotRoot){
    events.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : dataSnapshotRoot.getChildren()){
        Events e = new Events();
        e.setName(dataSnapshot.getValue(Events.class).getName());
        events.add(e.getName());
    }
    if(events.size()>0){
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView2,events);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"There is no data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen is my qestion hard to understand? Should I explain in some other way?

Comment: @Frank I have added code now that get the name from my Object but how do I pass multiple things to my custom listview layout. Check the update.

Comment: "and the childs...will be additional information for each listitem". Where will the information be displayed? On the list item itself or in an activity that opens when the list item is clicked?

Comment: @quidproquo The information will be displayed on the list item itself.

Comment: @quidproquo Now **textView2** get the **name** and what I want to do is add value of **nature** to another **textView** in the same layout

Answer (score 1):

You've to use Cardview layout instead of a Listview.